# Validate base64 zip xml file by xsd

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd, sharpziplib

I need validate base64 zip xml file. Zipped by SharpZipLib.Zip. I create test code for validation, but when run reader.Read() method I have error - System.Xml.XmlException, '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.

```
string xsdPath = @"c:\Test.xsd";
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(Resources.TestBase64);
using (Stream memInput = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
using (ZipInputStream input = new ZipInputStream(memInput))
{
    ZipEntry entry = input.GetNextEntry();

    byte[] newBytes = new byte[entry.Size];

    XmlSchemaSet sc = new XmlSchemaSet();
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText(xsdPath, Encoding.Default));

    // Add the schema to the collection.
    sc.Add(null, new XmlTextReader(stringReader));

    // Set the validation settings.
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    settings.Schemas = sc;
    settings.CheckCharacters = false;
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);

    MemoryStream streamXml = new MemoryStream(newBytes);
    streamXml.Position = 0;
    StreamReader readerXml = new StreamReader(streamXml, Encoding.UTF8);

    // Create the XmlReader object.
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(readerXml, settings);

    // Parse the file.  
    while (reader.Read())
    {


    }
}

private static void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    var result = string.Format("Validation Error: {0} -- {1}", e.Message,e.Exception.LineNumber);
}
```

Comment: without the actual xml we won`t be able to help you. As it seems you have some invalid characters in your XML.

Comment: The problem was the absence of: input.Read(newBytes, 0, newBytes.Length);

Comment: @zrabzdn Why are you copying the input stream in the first place? Why not use that stream in the `StreamReader` directly?

Comment: @Luaan This is a test method, after refactoring can be used in the StreamReader